# Swift String appending with optional nil

Tags: ios, string, swift

The second way of printing an optional value is correct, but is there any shorter way to write code with the same effect? I.e. Where before unwrapping the value we check if its nil.

```
var city:String?

func printCityName(){
    let name = "NY"
    //Fails (First Way)
    print("Name of the city is \(name + city)")
    //Success (Second Way)
    if let cityCheckConstant = city {
       print("Name of the city is \(name + cityCheckConstant)")
    }
}
```

Comment: you can just use `if city != nil`... You don't need to assign the unwrapped optional to a new constant.

Comment: You could write `_ = city.flatMap { print("Name of the city is \(name + $0)") }` (Swift 2), but I would always prefer your code in favor of this obfuscated version.

Comment: The city !=nil , is simple. When I tried with flatMap, "$0" throws error and the autocorrect changes it to city.flatMap { print("Name of the city is \(name + ($0 as String))") }

Comment: @andyPaul: Then `city` is not a `String?`. Perhaps a `NSString?` ?

Comment: @MartinR , My Mistake, it is String. Later on I had changed to NSString in the playground. So, was getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest would be with `map` on the Optional:

```
var city : String?

func printCityName() {
    let name = "NY"
    city.map{ print("Name of the city is \(name + $0)") }
}
```

Or guards are nice too:

```
func printCityName(){
    let name = "NY"
    guard let city = city else { return }
    print("Name of the city is \(name + city)")
}
```

Your code was alright though, a more readable version is always better when it does the same. One thing to mention: You don't have to use a different name for the variable in the `if let`:

```
func printCityName(){
    let name = "NY"
    if let city = city {
        print("Name of the city is \(name + city)")
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't like to use `_ =` every time with the first version, you can extend `Optional`:

```
extension Optional {
    func with(@noescape f: Wrapped throws -> Void) rethrows {
        _ = try map(f)
    }
}
```

which makes it possible to do this:

```
func printCityName() {
    let name = "NY"
    city.with{ print("Name of the city is \(name + $0)") }
}
```

without a warning

Comment: if let city = city , will create a constant but it will make code more readable. So, if city != nil would be better, as it would not create a constant. (Mentioned by @Paulw11 in comments with questions)

Comment: @andyPaul I really don't think that the compiler is that bad that it always copies the value when `if let` unwrapping. We shouldn't sacrifice clarity for such pseudo micro-optimizations.

Comment: Remark: The  `city.map { ... }` statement causes an "expression result unused" warning in Xcode 7 beta 6 (the return type is `()?` aka "optional Void"). I don't know if that is intended or a bug, but it can be silenced with `_ = city.map { ... }`.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah that's not a bug, the return type is really `()?` because `print` returns `()`. Didn't see it because I was using a playground. The `_ = ` is kind of ugly, yeah.

Comment: @MartinR Updated my answer :D